# How to verify that Redshift are really DISK FULL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Question from Redshift newbies: I copy data using AWS datapipeline but it FAILED and log said

> "ERROR: Disk Full Detail:
>   ----------------------------------------------- error: Disk Full code: 1016 context: node: 0 query: 2070045 location: fdisk_api.cpp:343
>   process: query0_49 [pid=15048] "

I'd like to know how could we check if Redshift is really disk full via CLI or web console, any comments or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a single node and have SQL access to the cluster (e.g. via psql), you can run:

```
select
  sum(capacity)/1024 as capacity_gbytes, 
  sum(used)/1024 as used_gbytes, 
  (sum(capacity) - sum(used))/1024 as free_gbytes 
from 
  stv_partitions where part_begin=0;
```

This article has more: https://www.flydata.com/blog/querying-free-disk-space-on-redshift/

Answer (score 2):

You can check that in CloudWatch console. In the left bar, you'll see bunch of AWS services under the 'Metrics' heading. Click on Redshift. In that, look for the 'PercentageDiskSpaceUsed' metric for the concerned cluster.

Also, do remember that this metric is separately available for each compute node.